# instagram API responds APISubscriptionError Invalid Response

Tags: php, instagram

I have a few subscriptions. Time to time subscription ends and I start the ended subscription again.

Now, my most used subscriptions ended and I can't start again. I'm working in PHP. Nothing has changed in my code, but now I get error while trying to subscribe.

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APISubscriptionError","code":400,"error_message":"Invalid response"}}
```

My other subscriptions are still active but 4 of them are failing. I couldn't fix it.

Edit - Code:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
$client_id='XXXXX';
$client_secret='XXXXX';
$object = 'tag';
$aspect = 'media';
$object_id = 'XXXXX';
$verify_token='XXXXX';
$callback_url = 'http://XXXXX/callback.php';

$attachment =  array(
'client_id' => $client_id,
'client_secret' => $client_secret,
'object' => $object,
'object_id' => $object_id,
'aspect' => $aspect,
'verify_token' => $verify_token,
'callback_url'=>$callback_url
);

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: You need to provide the code you're using to request a subscription for others to help.

Answer (score -2):

Instagram sends a GET request to uour callback_url and wants you to response with hub.challenge.